# How do Angry birds, clash of clans or Mini series verify in-App purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm making a new app, and already implemented In-app purchase (IAP), I have tried several solutions from here to verify these purchases but without any success to stop those who use IAP hacks, I already have a server set with the next code:

```
    PHP:

$url = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';

$encodedData = json_encode( Array( 
    'receipt-data' => $_POST["receipt"] 
) );


//Open a Connection using POST method, as it is required to use POST method.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encodedData);
$encodedResponse = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode( $encodedResponse );


echo "Status Code:";

echo $response->{'status'};
```

And

```
Objective-C:

NSString *completeString = @"http://www.example.com/verify.php";

NSURL *urlForValidation = [NSURL URLWithString:completeString];

NSMutableURLRequest *validationRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlForValidation];

[validationRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *strTest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"receipt=%@", [self base64forData:transaction.transactionReceipt]];

[validationRequest setHTTPBody:[strTest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:validationRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: responseData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", response);
```

But after testing with a jailbroken device using IAP hacks it will bypass the check and unlock IAP.

I know apps like angry birds, clash of clans, and mini gore series do very well verifying purchases, I would like to know what can I do to have the same kind of checks.

Comment: Under iOS 7 you can use https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS

Comment: Thanks for that, but I also need to verify iOS 6 IAP

Comment: VerifyStoreReceipt is a pretty good answer. Even if backwards compatibility is not possible, I would change it to an answer, not just a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Minigore does not use extra verification methods.
I assume neither does Angry Birds.
Clash of Clans is heavily login- and server-based so the assumption is that they have more control over verification.

Noting the comment above about a verification system, for something that would work on any build target, without a server and unique user accounts I don't believe there is much you can do. Even with the server and user accounts, matching the data to find cheaters may take a fair bit of effort, so making this system should not be a priority until you have a successful game on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

There are two github projects that may help you. Both by mattt. The first is [CargoBay](https://github.com/mattt/CargoBay) which is an objective c library for validating purchases. The second is [Venice](https://github.com/nomad/venice) which is a ruby gem for validating purchases on a server (or from the command line).